# Multiple Inner Joins and one to one // one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

I have this query below..  All of the relationships of the tables are one to one relationships except for ASSOCPRODUCTS table where there are two products per order.  Everything seems to work fine, except for that my query returns only one row, and thus, will only return ONE product id when there are in fact two.  I understand why it's only pulling one, in that there is only ONE order per orderID, but there are two Associated Products for each contract and I need to get each product id.  in the Assocproducts table, each product gets its own row, as it is a one to many wit the contracts table.

Is it possible to get that information using inner joins, or do I need to run another query?

```
$orderid = $_POST['orderid'];

$res = mysql_query ("
SELECT company.name as cname, 
    orders.datemade as datemade
    orders.p1quantity as p1q, 
    orders.p2quantity as p2q, 
    assocproducts.productid as pid,
    assocproducts.price as pprice, 
    inventory.name as pname, 
    inventory.quantity as pquantity 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN contracts ON (contracts.id = orders.contractid)
INNER JOIN company ON (contracts.companyid = company.id) 
INNER JOIN assocproducts ON (contracts.id = assocproducts.contractid) 
INNER JOIN inventory ON (assocproducts.productid = inventory.id) 
WHERE orders.id = " . $orderid);

$order = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Please let me know if I need to give more information.

$order isn't in a loop, because I need to display ONLY the order info for this specific order.  It's an AJAX trigger on click.

Thanks!

Comment: try with `left join` instead.

Comment: assuming left join does the trick, how do I access the TWO returned products?  I know how to grab everything else.

Comment: If you want to return more than 2 products ID, use `where orders.id in ($orderid1,$orderid2)`

Comment: that didn't work.  There is only one order, and the order has an associated contract, and the contract has two associated products.

Comment: if you can, place in SQLFiddle your structure and part of the example to create you the query, like this it's a little bit more complicate

Comment: Yeah I'll try to do that when I get a chance, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're wrong stating that only one row is returned. I created a fresh schema with only the columns used in your query, populated it with sample data and got out all matching results. I think the problem is with your usage of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function. Semantics of [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) are clear:

> Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or **FALSE** if there are no more rows.

so my guess is you never call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` again.

Given semantics of `INNER JOIN` and your data constraints, your query will *always produce 0 or 1 rows*. If you don't know why - please read [SQL JOIN types & behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). So, you have two options to fetch order details *and* information about associated products:

1. Use two separate select statements - one for order details (always 1 row), second for associated products (2 rows). Iterate on results of the second query - you will get information about one product for each row fetched.
2. Keep your existing query, but change the way you retrieve data from it by iterating over all rows (note that order information will be present in all fetched rows and will be the same for all of them):

   ```
   $firstRow = true;
   while (($order_product = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== FALSE) {
       if ($firstRow) {
           // do something with order info
           // but don't repeat it for consecutive rows
           $firstRow = false;
       }
       // do something with currently fetched associated product info
   }
   ```

It's a matter of taste, but I'd go with the first option - it looks less hacky.

Comment: I ended up using another query, as you suggested.  Thank you, kind sir!